# Event click on <a> tag after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, popup

i have a question here, someone can help me plz.

I'am a newbie in `magento` developer, now i have to work with `onepage checkout`, and here my issue.

when my customer click in `Place Order Button`, it run my function below to take a `Pay Key` by `cUrl` to `PayPal`:

```
    function popUpPaypal() {
            $j.ajax({
                url: '<?= Mage::getBaseUrl()?>xpayment/index', //call my controller to take Pay Key
                type: 'POST',
                data: {},
                success: function (res) {
                    $j('#payPalRedirect').attr('href', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=' + res + '&expType=mini'); //set a tag href with the paykey
                //** and in here i want to call <a> tag below to show a paypal popup **
                }
            });
        }
```

the `href` are change but i try many time, many event like `$j('#payPalRedirect').click()` or `$j('#payPalRedirect').trigger('click')` but it never so popup for me, anyone can help me or give me a solution plz.

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a id="payPalRedirect"
   href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-3P78939660878441R&expType=mini"
   target="_blank">Complete PayPal Payment</a>
<script>
    var returnFromPayPal = function () {
        alert("Returned from PayPal");
    }
    var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({ trigger: 'payPalRedirect', expType: 'mini', callbackFunction: 'returnFromPayPal' });
</script>
```

Comment: It's just as simple as calling `$j('#payPaylRedirect').click()`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yah, thanks but not work with `.click()` because the `.click()` call the `onClick` of <a> tag, not call the `href` in <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.on

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#payPaylRedirect', function () {

// Do click stuff here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you right... 
You are trying to simulate click event on "a" tag?

If that is the problem then you must write click trigger like this:

```
$(".some-a-href-class")[0].click();
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8cV8W/1/)